# The word 'module' is not blue when I type it in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran

I use Fortran 90 via Force 2.0, with a 64bits pc under windows 10.

When I try to create a module by typing module, it just doesn't work, the word stay black.

How to solve this ?

Thanks you.

Comment: I have not worked with Force 2.0. But a quick search on the web reveals that this IDE is developed for FORTRAN77. The `module` keyword is a Fortran 90 feature. Try using Nodepad++ or Microsoft Visual Studio + Intel Visual Compiler instead of Force 2.0.

Comment: Not my thing at all as I don't do Windows but googling suggests Eclipse+Photran might be another option

Comment: You might want to check out vscode and its Fortran plugins: Modern Fortran, Fortran Intellisense, Native Debug, Fortran Breakpoint Support.

Comment: Thank you very much, I must be pretty terrible at searching on Google since I didn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: @JonathanBalde Helps to know the answer you are looking for ;)